# Когда setTimeout в цикле, - сделать clearTimeout, а потом запустить

Tags: javascript

Привожу код, в котором идет смена цвета дива по кругу в цикле : зеленый/красный/желтый.
В примере такой цикл запускается *по кнопке*. Как правильно сделать остановку и старт
такой смены цвета, чтобы не *накладывалось* выполнение цикла?

---

```js
function fun_1(s) { // s -> start/stop;

  var timeoutID = '';

  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

       timeoutID = setTimeout(function(x) { return function() {

           var c = '', doc = document.getElementById('sss');
           if(x==1){c='green'};
           if(x==2){c='red'};
              doc.style.background = c;
           if(x==3){
            c='yellow';
            doc.style.background = c;
            fun_1();
           };

       }; }(i), 1200*i);
  }
}

// стоп
function fun_2() {
 // fun_1('stop');
 // clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
// старт
function fun_3() {
 // fun_1('start');
 // 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1: Запуск : зеленый/красный/желтый по кругу." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_1()">
</br>
<input type="button" value="2: Стоп." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_2()">
</br>
<input type="button" value="3: Старт." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_3()">
</br>
<div id="sss" style="width:50%; height:30px; background:#ccc"> </div>
```

Comment: ой-ой-ой, а зачем `четыре` таймера? у вас же только **один** активный цвет

Comment: Останавливать уже запущенный таймер перед запуском нового?

Comment: @ilyaplot, здесь запускается несколько таймеров, а сохраняется только один - при всем желании нельзя будет все остановить

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно

Comment: @Grundy Тогда храните id таймеров в разных переменных или объекте. Сейчас Вы перезаписываете id таймера несколько раз, потому хранится только последний id таймера.

Comment: буду пробовать хранить id таймера в массиве ... там я убрал из кода лишнее : [ if(s=='stop') return; ] - остатки от экспериментов ... думал есть какой патерн для подобного решения, спасибо.

Comment: @ilyaplot, я бы не запускал несколько таймеров сразу :-) ну и автор вопроса - не я :):):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае вместо цикла лучше использовать [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```js
var timer,
  colorsState = {
    'green': 'yellow',
    'yellow': 'red',
    'red': 'green'
  },
  currentColor,
  doc = document.getElementById('sss');

function fun_1(s) { // s -> start/stop;
  if (s == 'stop') { // если стоп
    clearInterval(timer); //останавливаем таймер
    timer = undefined;
    return;
  }
  if (s == 'start' && timer) return; //если старт, таймер уже запущен - ничего не делаем
  if (s != 'start') { // если запуск
    clearInterval(timer); //останавливаем таймер
    doc.style.background = currentColor = 'green'; //сбрасываем на зеленый цвет
  }

  timer = setInterval(function() { //запускаем таймер
    doc.style.background = currentColor = colorsState[currentColor]; //устанавливаем следующий цвет

  }, 400);
}

// стоп
function fun_2() {
  fun_1('stop');
}

// старт
function fun_3() {
  fun_1('start');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1: Запуск : зеленый/красный/желтый по кругу." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_1()">
<br />
<input type="button" value="2: Стоп." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_2()">
<br />
<input type="button" value="3: Старт." style="width:50%; height:26px; font-size:12px" onclick="fun_3()">
<br />
<div id="sss" style="width:50%; height:30px; background:#ccc"></div>
```

Comment: да, работает, как надо, спасибо.